# How to change default git commit message

Tags: git, commit

I've added some changes on commit message in prepare-commit-msg file and then I exec this command

> git config --global commit.template .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg

After that when I do git commit I receive something like this

> 40 lines of my changes and then

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.   
# Explicit paths specified without -i nor -o; assuming --only paths... 
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#
#       modified:   test
#
```

Question is there any chance to show this default message on the top? Or better permanently remove this message?

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be mixing up the `commit.template` option (which provides a default value for the `--template` option to `git commit`) with the `prepare-commit-message` hook.

Normally `git commit` uses the following sequence of operations:

1. Run the pre-commit hook, if it exists and is runnable.  If it exits non-zero, abort the commit.
2. Copy any specified or configured template (see below) to a temporary file.  If there is no template or the template path is not readable, begin with an empty temporary file.
3. Add the lines `# Please enter the commit message ...` and the output of `git status`.
4. Run the `prepare-commit-message` hook, if it exists and is runnable, on the temporary file.
5. Open up your editor on the temporary file.  (Your editor is set from `$GIT_EDITOR`, the `core.editor` configuration, `$VISUAL`, `$EDITOR`, or a built-in default, whichever is the first one set.)
6. Once you exit your editor, make the commit, or stop the commit, depending on whether you have provided a commit message.

If you use the `-f` or `-m` options, steps 2, 3, and 5 are normally skipped (though you can force git to open your editor by adding `--edit`).  Presumably you have not used those options.

What the `--template` option does—and hence what `commit.template` does—is to provides the path name of a file that `git commit` will copy in step 2.  This does not affect lines added in step 3.  While the path `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-message` *is* (probably) a file git can read, it's not a very sensible name for your template, since if that same path is made executable, the file will become runnable and step 4 will probably behave badly.

You can tell `git commit` *not* to do step 3 by adding `--no-status`.  (Also, as a somewhat odd side effect, `--no-edit`, which explicitly suppresses step 5, also suppresses step 3.)

Or, you can make use of step 4 to eliminate some or all of the `git status` output and standard `# Please enter...` message.  The `prepare-commit-message` hook can make arbitrary changes to the template file.

Note that `--cleanup=<mode>` affects what winds up in the final commit message, and also the processing of step 6.  For details see [the `git commit` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html).

Comment: Oh thanks for answer but as for now I don't understand why there can by problem with step 4? Can you explain that?

Also I found that command -> 
    > git config --global commit.status false

And as I can see this command delete from git commit this template "Please enter..." question is it a good way to do like this?

Also how can I push this changes (on config file) to other branches?Or should I change it on master branch?

Comment: At step 4, git will *run* the file in `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-message`, if it can.  If you put ordinary text in this file, what happens if git manages to run it?  As for `commit.status`, setting it to `false` makes `--no-status` the default, so that's a reasonable way to do it.  Meanwhile your configuration (whether `--global` or local) is not something git changes when changing branches, so there is no issue there.